# How to use the latest version of Truffle Contract in a web page?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract

I'm trying to use version 4.0.0 of truffle-contract in a browser app, so no NodeJS, no require or anything. So I followed the instructions in the doc, downloaded truffle-contract in non-minified format from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/truffle-contract@4.0.0/dist/truffle-contract.js, downloaded the latest version of ethers.js from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ethers@4.0.20/dist/ethers.min.js, added the script tags in my HTML page:

```
<script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ethers.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

but now when I load the page, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: EthersAbi is not a constructor
at Object.74.ethers/utils/abi-coder (truffle-contract.js:14737)
at o (truffle-contract.js:1)
...
```

Is there any other dependency that is not documented, or does truffle-contract depend on another version of ethers.js?